# Mercurial: Re-merge into branch without new changes

Tags: version-control, merge, mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

**Our setup**

We are running a deployment setup with mercurial and Bitbucket where feature branches are merged into a branch called preDefault. When preDefault is tested, it is pushed to a branch called default which is then merged to production.

If any bugs are found on preDefault this branch will be reverted to the latest stable state of the branch. From here, we are supposed to be able to merge the working features into preDefault again and simply leave out the broken ones until they are fixed.

**But:**

Since I already have merged the feature branch into preDefault one time (in the beginning), then I'm not able to merge the same feature branch into preDefault again unless I make some changes to the code.

By now we are running out of ideas - we will be thankful if you have any?

/Oskar Konstantyner

Comment: When you say reverted, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: I'm updating to the latest stable version, and then merging the buggy version into the stable one while discarding all changes

Comment: Dummy merge is your biggest mistake: do nothing after `hg up tested`

Comment: Ok, we found a solution by updating to the tested branch, make the changes, and then merge the broken branch into the tested on while discarding all changes so that we didn't ended up with two heads.
Thank you for your help!